# The function in the .filter() is not working as I wanted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If my table looks like this in html

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>foo
        <td>bar
        <td>alpha
        <td>beta
        <td>seta

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>foo1
        <td>bar2
        <td>alpha3
        <td>beta3
        <td>seta3
    </tr>
</table>
```

And i was just going through jQuery for formatting the table.

```
//this one perfectly works
//this turns even columns into red!!
$("td").filter(':odd').addClass('colorRedClass');
```

But I want to use a function like this for the same! Is it possible?

```
//i returned the value ':odd' from the function!!
//this turns every column into red!!
//this is not working as expected!!
$("td").filter(function(){
        return ':odd';
    }).addClass('colorRedClass');
```

And colorRedClass is in CSS that has attribute color:red;

So, my question is, why can't the second one work? Why can't second one just change even columns into red? I am from c,c++, java background and as per my understanding, the return should work if I did the same way in those languages.

What am I missing?

Comment: You really should close your `<td>`. It isn't valid HTML, and your letting the browser guess where it closes, leading to possible unwanted behavior.

Comment: @Bigood: This _is_ valid in HTML 4.01 and HTML5.

Comment: @CBroe Didn't know this, forget my comment. [Here's a reference on W3 for ignorants like me](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you pass to filter is supposed to have the type:

```
Type: Function( Integer index, Element element ) => Boolean
```

So it expects you to return true if the element is to be included in the filtered set rather than use a selector.

You could use the index parameter to decide whether the element is odd:

```
$("td").filter(function(index){
    var isOdd = index % 2 === 1;
    return isOdd;
}).addClass('colorRedClass');
```